# Micro-ATX power supply screw alignment

Tags: power-supply, micro-atx

Most of the MicroATX cases have an offset top-left screw like this:

[image: PSU1]

But most of the MicroATX power supplies I'm finding have a rectangular configuration like this:

[image: PSU2]

Which is standard? Are there two standards? I'm trying to build a MicroATX, but I don't want to get stuck with something I can't find a good replacement for down the road.

UPDATE: I will try to clarify my question. When people buy MicroATX cases, which kind of power supply do they usually use? Do some MicroATX cases take regular ATX PSUs? Why am I seeing different PSU screw configurations for different cases sold as "MicroATX"? Is there a norm for MicroATX cases / PSUs, or is it random mix and match between several different types?

Comment: The case in question is clearly an OEM case. Which is the reason the screws are in a weird place.

Comment: Some cases have 5 holes, for the regular & offset options. Either way, 3 screws rather than 4 is not going to be any kind of major issue.

Comment: @Ramhound By OEM do you mean standard ATX? This picture is from this case, which is listed as MicroATX: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16811154094 It seems to have screws for a standard PSU, but looks too small, so I am confused what would fit it.

Comment: @Tetsujin I was thinking of doing only 3 screws if needed, but I'm more concerned with how to if the PSU will actually fit. MicroATX PSUs appear to be physically smaller / flatter.

Comment: By OEM I mean ( Dell, HP, etc. ).  I based that assumption on the screenshot, which is a poor screenshot, the manual should have precise PSU measurements though.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the standards for power supplies:

http://www.formfactors.org/developer/specs/Power_Supply_Design_Guide_Desktop_Platform_Rev_1_2.pdf

On page 72 onward they show the different types of power supplies and where the screws have to go.  Technically any that fall into these categories are "standard power supplies"

Comment: I guess I shouldn't have used the word "standard". This guide is not very helpful for an ordinary consumer choosing the correct size of power supply for MicroATX, or learning why MicroATX cases have different PSU screw configurations, or which is the most popular / reasonable configuration to purchase. The only reference to MicroATX I could find in the entire 104 page document refers to the recommended fan size for providing proper air flow through a MicroATX case... I will try to update my question with better wording.

Comment: It has different MicroATX PSU requirements in there. What I was showing is that there are a few different standards that apply.  This guide shows you what is available out there. If you use a website such as Newegg you can determine which are most common configurations.